# How to optimize keywords in URLs for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, keywords, canonical-url

Can I write slightly different URLs for the same page and rank "equally" for both?

For example, I have a post URL like this:

```
http://example.com/rio-de-janeiro/onetitle-...
```

But I also would like to rank for searches like this:

```
http://example.com/rj/onetitle-...
```

So if the user searches for "rj onetitle" or "rio de janeiro onetitle" it won't matter, I can rank for both...

Can I use canonical URL's for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand some SEO principles:

1. keywords in URLs are not so powerful for SEO than you think
2. URLs must be chosen for users (to remember easily) before SEO

Moreover, you can rank on Google for *rj onetitle* and *janeiro onetitle* with only one of these URLs. You just need to work SEO of this page.

Otherwise, if you have just one of these URLs, it's perfect. If you already have these two URLs accessible for users, you need to choose one and put the `rel="canonical"` tag to the other.
More information about the `rel="canonical"` tag on [Google's support dedicated page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).

Comment: What about misspells? In a specific case I have, Google doesn't seem to recognize that these two words are "synonyms" (one letter difference). What can I do? I can't use a misspelled word in my content just to do SEO.

Comment: Just use the right word in your page content and URL (think about users first). After, you can use as anchor text for your backlinks all the word variations. And Google could rank your page for all these terms and synonyms.